# "dart: Command not found" when running Dart commands in Codemagic

Tags: dart, continuous-integration, codemagic

when I try to run Dart commands (even simple `dart --version`) in Codemagic it fails with an error saying `dart: command not found`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to overcome the issue you need to update your scripts to run `$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/dart` instead.

There is no separate Dart SDK on Codemagic build machines, only Flutter SDK and you can use the Dart version shipped with Flutter.

For instance

```
#!/bin/sh

$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/dart --version
```

Comment: Can you share your scripts for running dart command in codemagic?

Comment: Or can you complete my simple script? --> `#!/bin/sh

// TODO:
dart --version`

Comment: Thanks, it's working